# Redirection operation writes output of order in file

Tags: c, stdio

I have a simple C file, that writes to the standard output using `printf` and `write(1,..)` functions.

**File: main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("Mars\n");
    fsync(1);
    write(1,"Ola\n",4);
    write(1,"Earth\n",6);
}

> gcc main.c -o test
```

When I redirect the output to a file, I see different order than the output in the terminal. It seems, that when I am using redirection `write(..)` writes before than `printf(..)`, even tough, `printf()` is earlier in code and there is a `fsync(..)` in between.

Is there some variant of the *redirection operator* that will ensure order, or am I doing something wrong.

**Output in terminal**:

```
> ./test

Hello
Mars
Ola
Earth
```

**Output in `out` file**:

```
> ./test >out
# or ./test|tee out

> cat out

Ola
Earth
Hello
Mars
```

Comment: Try replacing `fsync(1)` with `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: You really should never mix buffered writes and non-buffered writes. Use one of `write` or `printf`, but not both.

Comment: @tadman: Not realistic.  Sometimes you want to use a library, that library may do I/O its own way.  So calling `fflush` between output of different types is a lot more practical solution.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying you can't do it, or that you might not be forced to do it, but that you should avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` writes to the C stream `stdout`, which is buffered by the C standard library routines and ultimately written to Unix file descriptor 1.

`fsync` and `write` operate on Unix file descriptor 1. `fsync` flushes data from file descriptor 1, but it has no effect on the buffers of the streams of the C standard library.

The C standard library I/O routines operate differently depending on whether standard output is going to a terminal or to a file. This is detected during program start-up. When output is going to a terminal, it is deemed important to get it to the user, and the buffer is flushed when `\n` is written to a stream. This is called *line buffered*, and output to a terminal is set to line buffered by default.

When output is going to a file, it is not deemed important to flush it promptly, since a user is not expected to see it right away and performance is better if output is fully buffered. So the buffer is flushed only when it is full, the stream is closed, or an explicit flush request is made. This is called *fully buffered*, and output to a file is set to fully buffered by default.

This is generally addressed in C 2018 7.21.3, in which paragraph 7 says:

> … the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

(When the output is a terminal, the C implementation may also use *unbuffered* mode instead of *line buffered*, in which case all characters are sent to the terminal as soon as they are written. This is uncommon.)

You can explicitly requesting flushing of `stdout` with `fflush(stdout)`.

After `stdout` is opened but before any other operation is performed on it, you can change its buffer method with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, mode, 0)`, where `mode` is `_IOFBF`, `_IOLBF`, or `_IONBF` for full, line, or no buffering, respectively. (You can also pass a `char` array and its size in place of `NULL` and `0`, and the library will use that array for the buffer, after which you should not use the array for any other purpose. If you pass `NULL` and a size, the library may use that size to perform its own buffer allocation, but that is not guaranteed.) `setvbuf` returns an `int` that may be non-zero if it cannot honor the request.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. **Question:** When I strace, I see `printf("Hello")` will finally call `write(1,"Hello",5)`. So if I unbuffer the stdout stream, in the C stdlib, the Kernel buffer will anyways be used, just as if I called the `write()` myself. Right?

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the dup2 system call: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dup-dup2-linux-system-call/

you can redirect stdoutput / input to a file